# How to find rows with fully contained subset of tags

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to find a query that will return me records of objects that contain, in terms of its tags, objects of another type.

To clarify: I have three types of objects: data, item, and tag. Data and item both can have zero or more tags. I am trying to construct a query that, given an ID for a 'data' record, would return all item records whose tags are fully contained within those of 'data'.

So, given a data item with tags `[foo, bar, baz]`, the query would result in an item with tags `[foo]`, or `[foo, baz]`, or `[foo, bar, baz]`, but not an item with tags `[foo, bar, baz, quux]` (too many), nor an item with tags `[foo, blah]` (no `blah` in data record).

I am having trouble wrapping my head around the joins required for a query like this.

The tables are `data` with join table `data_tags`, `item` with join table `item_tags`, and `tag`. I *think* I need to be looking at something like this (pseudo-code, sort of):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT item_tags.item_id
  FROM data_tags CROSS JOIN item_tags
 WHERE item_tags.tag_id = data_tags.tag_id
   AND data_tags.data_id = ?
```

... but I think this will return all the `item`s that have *any* kind of overlap with the tags in `data`, and I *only* want the items that have *all* of their tags in data record.

So let's say I have a `data` record:

```
+----+------+
| id | name | 
+----+------+
|  1 | Test |
+----+------+
```

with tags in `data_tags`:

```
+----+---------+--------+
| id | data_id | tag_id |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 |       1 |      1 | // Foo
|  2 |       1 |      2 | // Bar
|  3 |       1 |      3 | // Baz
+----+---------+--------+
```

And two items (not showing `item_tags` in the interest of brevity):

```
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Item A | // Tags: Foo, Bar
|  2 | Item B | // Tags: Foo, Quux
+----+--------+
```

The query should return `Item A` but not `Item B`. This seems like a fairly simple problem, but I cannot get my head around it. Any help?

Included below are the DDL statements:

```
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `data_tags` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `data_id` (`data_id`),
  KEY `tag_id` (`tag_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `data_tags_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`data_id`) REFERENCES `data` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `data_tags_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tag` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `item` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `item_tags` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `item_id` (`item_id`),
  KEY `tag_id` (`tag_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `item_tags_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `item` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `item_tags_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tag` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `tag` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Rather than a cross join try

SELECT DISTINCT item_tags.item_id
  FROM data_tags INNER JOIN item_tags
 On item_tags.tag_id = data_tags.tag_id
   WHERE data_tags.data_id = ?

Comment: Zohar, thank you (and apologies for the rookie mistake) -- I've attached the DDL statement below my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the results you want by counting the tags from each item and comparing them with the number of matching tags from the data record. As long as they are the same, the item has a subset of the tags of the data record.

```
SELECT i.name
FROM items i
JOIN item_tags it ON it.item_id = i.id
LEFT JOIN data_tags dt ON dt.tag_id = it.tag_id
LEFT JOIN data d ON d.id = dt.data_id AND d.id = 1
GROUP BY i.name
HAVING COUNT(it.tag_id) = COUNT(dt.tag_id)
```

I created a demo with a couple of extra items:

```
name    tags
Item A  Foo,Bar
Item B  Foo,Quux
Item C  Foo,Bar,Baz
Item D  Foo,Bar,Baz,Quux
```

for which the output of the above query is:

```
name
Item A
Item C
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9mUMkUCWsAMzvwYpSrX7Py/0)

Comment: Nick, thanks a lot! This is exactly it. I had a hunch that grouping and then matching the counts would do it, but I did not know how to get there; I was approaching it from the other direction, doing a cross join on the data tags; I did not think to start with the item tags, but that's the trick.